# I want to make responsive random location image

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML code. I want to make this responsive when I resize the screen smaller or larger.

```
<div class="fixed">
    <a href="contactX.html"><img src="images/contact.png" class="img-responsive alt="icon 01" width="300px"></a>                    
</div>
<div class="fixed1">
    <a href="news.php"><img src="images/news.png" class="img-responsive alt="icon 01" width="300px"></a>
</div>
<div class="fixed2">
    <a href="success.php"><img src="images/success.png" class="img-responsive" alt="icon 01" width="300px" ></a>
</div>
<div class="fixed3">
    <a href="product.html"><img src="images/product.png" class="img-responsive" alt="icon 01" width="300px"></a>
</div>
<div class="fixed4">
    <a href="aboutus.html"><img src="images/company_profile.png" class="img-responsive" alt="icon 01" width="300px"></a>
</div>
```

Heres my CSS code:

```css
div.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    left: 450px;
    top:30px;
}
div.fixed1 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 510px;
    top:130px;
}

div.fixed2 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 530px;
    top:230px;
}
div.fixed3 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 550px;
    top:330px;
}
div.fixed4 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 420px;
    top:650px;
}
```

I want to make this responsive. So if I adjust my screen size the positions will auto adjust as my screen size. Please give me some advice and suggestion.

Comment: So you want to add an image whose size changes with the screen size? Am I right?

Comment: @Joshua Gani Wijaya Take a look at this javascript library.. http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Yes  just like that.

Comment: @JoshuaGaniWijaya Why don't you use bootstrap?

Comment: @user7397787 sure bootstrap will do the job, but my web content is not set as normal web. It make curve order around my background image.